# GROUP BY with MAX(DATE) in table with composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to list the BarCode for each SKU in a table but the BarCode is different in some cases, so i want to get from one sku one barcode and the barcode returned should be the one with the UpdateDate most recent.

Example:

```
StoreID     SKU    BarCode           UpdateDate
-------------------------------------------------------------
1           95810  28471000000       10/06/2016 04:20:00 a.m.
1           95810  30040050033       01/03/2012 01:00:00 a.m.
2           44320  65453102001       15/05/2010 01:00:00 a.m.
2           44320  12343102001       01/01/2015 01:00:00 a.m.
```

The desired result should be:

```
StoreID     SKU    BarCode           UpdateDate
-------------------------------------------------------------
1           95810  28471000000       10/06/2016 04:20:00 a.m.
2           44320  12343102001       01/01/2015 01:00:00 a.m.
```

I have tried using

```
SELECT  
    t.SKU, r.MaxTime
FROM
    (SELECT 
         P.SKU, MAX(P.Fec_Movto) as MaxTime
     FROM 
         Productos as P
     GROUP BY 
         P.SKU) r
INNER JOIN 
    Productos t ON t.SKU = r.SKU AND t.Fec_Movto = r.MaxTime
```

but the problem here is that primary key is a composite primary key so it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

may be use row_number like

```
select * from 
( select StoreID,SKU,BarCode,UpdateDate
,row_number() over ( partition by SKU order by UpdateDate desc) rowid
from Productos ) t
where rowid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT p.StoreId, p.SKU, p.Barcode, p.UpdateDate FROM AProductos p 
JOIN(  SELECT StoreId, SKU, MAX(UpdateDate) as MaxTime
 FROM AProductos
GROUP BY StoreId, SKU
) r ON  p.StoreId   = r.StoreId
AND p.SKU       = r.SKU 
AND p.UpdateDate = r.MaxTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, isn't the answer obvious? `SKU` is just part of the key, so don't use `SKU` without the other part `StoreID`.

```
SELECT p.StoreId, p.SKU, p.Barcode, p.Fec_Movto
FROM Productos p
JOIN
(
  SELECT StoreId, SKU, MAX(Fec_Movto) as MaxTime
  FROM Productos
  GROUP BY StoreId, SKU
) r ON  p.StoreId   = r.StoreId
    AND p.SKU       = r.SKU 
    AND p.Fec_Movto = r.MaxTime;
```

An alternative would be to rank the rows, so you don't have to access the table twice:

```
SELECT StoreId, SKU, Barcode, Fec_Movto
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    SKU,
    Fec_Movto,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StoreId, SKU ORDER BY Fec_Movto DESC) AS rn
  FROM Productos
) ranked
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUTER APPLY:

```
SELECT distinct  main.StoreId, main.SKU, b.Barcode, b.UpdateDate
FROM Productos  as main
Outer Apply (Select Top 1 
                    SKU, BarCode, UpdateDate
            from Productos as sub
            where main.SKU = sub.SKU
            Order by sub.UpdateDate desc
             ) b
```